# Run terminal as superuser

Tags: gnome-terminal, root

How can I activate the terminal to be run as superuser? I don't see an icon nor know the command line to do so.

Answer (score 7):

You can add a shortcut that runs `gksudo gnome-terminal`, or simply run `sudo -i` inside an already running one to become root.

Comment: Instead of `sudo -i` you can also use `sudo -s` (this is easier to remember for me, and it doesn't change my $HOME env var).